# Python 3.8 lzma decompress huge file incremental input and output

Tags: python, xz

I am looking to do, in Python 3.8, the equivalent of:

```
xz --decompress --stdout < hugefile.xz > hugefile.out
```

where ***neither*** the input nor output might fit well in memory.

As I read the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#lzma.LZMADecompressor
I could use **LZMADecompressor** to process incrementally available input, and I could use its **decompress**() function to produce output incrementally.

However it seems that **LZMADecompressor** puts its entire decompressed output into a single memory buffer, and **decompress**() reads its entire compressed input from a single input memory buffer.

Granted, the documentation confuses me as to when the input and/or output can be incremental.

So I figure I will have to spawn a separate child process to execute the "xz" binary.

Is there anyway of using the lzma Python module for this task?

Comment: Apart from potential portability problems (i.e., **xz** may not be installed) I'd be inclined to execute a subprocess. If the lzma module had a clearly defined streaming mechanism then that would be fine but that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Yes, I suspect you're right.  Well said.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the low-level `LZMADecompressor`, use [`lzma.open`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/lzma.html#lzma.open) to get a file object. Then, you can copy data into an other file object with the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html) module:

```py
import lzma
import shutil

with lzma.open("hugefile.xz", "rb") as fsrc:
    with open("hugefile.out", "wb") as fdst:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
```

Internally, `shutils.copyfileobj` reads and write data in chunks, and the LZMA decompression is done on the fly. This avoids decompressing the whole data into memory.